# Python: Deleting a section from a PE file

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I am working with PE binaries using Python and the pefile library. For reading information out of a binary and rewriting certain bytes, this library does it job really well. But now I want to delete a section from the file completely.

How would I do that? The only code I found concerning this task is in the function `pop_back()` at http://goo.gl/YYl5Vb. But this code only removes the last section while I need to be able to remove any section.

I suppose, I could remove the raw section data with something like

```
dead_sect_start = dead_sect.PointerToRawData
dead_sect_ed = dead_sect.PointerToRawData + dead_sect.SizeOfRawData
pe.__data__ = pe.__data__[:dead_sect_start] + pe.__data__[dead_sect_end:])
```

where pe is my parsed binary and dead_sect the section I want to remove.

But then, how do I fix the section headers? I don't think I would get it right if I started to mangle with the single header bytes on my own. Isn't there some support for this in the pefile library? Or some code, someone more competent than me wrote?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have the source code of the `pop_back()` function, just modify that to suit your needs:

```
def remove(self, index):
    """Removes a section of the section table.
       Deletes the section header in the section table, the data of the section
       in the file, removes the section in the sections list of pefile and adjusts
       the sizes in the optional header.
    """

    # Checking if the section list is long enough to actually remove index.
    if (self.pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections > index
        and self.pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections == len(self.pe.sections)):

        # Stripping the data of the section from the file.
        if self.pe.sections[index].SizeOfRawData != 0:
            self.pe.__data__ = 
                (self.pe.__data__[:self.pe.sections[index].PointerToRawData] +
                 self.pe.__data__[self.pe.sections[index].PointerToRawData +
                 self.pe.sections[index].SizeOfRawData:])

        # Overwriting the section header in the binary with nulls.
        # Getting the address of the section table and manually overwriting
        # the header with nulls unfortunally didn't work out.
        self.pe.sections[index].Name = '\x00'*8
        self.pe.sections[index].Misc_VirtualSize = 0x00000000
        self.pe.sections[index].VirtualAddress = 0x00000000
        self.pe.sections[index].SizeOfRawData = 0x00000000
        self.pe.sections[index].PointerToRawData = 0x00000000
        self.pe.sections[index].PointerToRelocations = 0x00000000
        self.pe.sections[index].PointerToLinenumbers = 0x00000000
        self.pe.sections[index].NumberOfRelocations = 0x0000
        self.pe.sections[index].NumberOfLinenumbers = 0x0000
        self.pe.sections[index].Characteristics = 0x00000000

        del self.pe.sections[index]

        self.pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections -= 1

        self.__adjust_optional_header()
    else:
        raise SectionDoublePError("There's no section to remove.")
```

You can add that function as-is to class `SectionDoubleP`, or just call it with an explicit self on a `SectionDoubleP` object:

```
remove(your_section_double_p, index_of_section_to_remove)
```

In the latter case, I would pick a better name than `remove()`, though :)

Comment: Unfortunally, this does not work. If I remove any section than the last with this code, LordPE shows me a section with no name and all values set to 0 in its place. The Offsets of all following sections remain unchanged to the original file, which cannot be correct, since we deleted the section data. And the last section disappears because we decreased NumberOfSections.

Comment: If you can add sections back in, you could try removing all sections back to ``index`` via ``pop_back()``, then add them all (excluding the one to remove) back in. Otherwise you probably have to dig deeper into the inner workings of the pefile library.